# After clicking on the ground，the gameobject attached the script move in a flash rather than few seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to write a script that would allow the gameobject attached CharacterController component to move towards the clicking-point for a few seconds after a clicked on a ground.But when Unity was in game state, I found that the object only moved for a flash after clicking.And when I was debugging the breakpoint, I found that the time-control parameter timer was counting correctly.

Unity version is 5.5.6 and use C# for programming.

```
void Start()
{
characterController = this.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Click();
    ClickMove();
}

void Click()
{
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 100))
    {
        //当射线碰撞到plane并且鼠标左键按下时
        if (hitInfo.transform.tag == "Terrain" && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))//注意判断条件使用了标签
        {
            //让cube方向朝向点击位置   
                transform.LookAt(hitInfo.point);                    
                offsetVec = hitInfo.point - transform.position;
                offsetVec = offsetVec / offsetVec.magnitude;
                MoveController = true;
        }

    }

    //向量的magnitude表示这个向量的长度，当cube离我们点击位置小于1的时候才停止移动，这个数值可以自己调节
}

void ClickMove()
{
    if (MoveController)
    {
        for (timer = 3.0f; timer >= 0; timer -= Time.deltaTime)
        {
            characterController.SimpleMove(offsetVec * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        MoveController = false;
    }

}
```

}

I expect the gameobject to move for a few seconds when I click the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for:

```
void ClickMove()
{
    if (MoveController)
    {
        characterController.SimpleMove(offsetVec * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        MoveController = false;
    }    
}
```

If you want the movement to be longer, you just have to change the speed (to make it slower) or the vector (to make it larger).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.And I find the problem caused by the FOR LOOP calculating too much in a moment.The problem solved.